# what does -ffast-math do?

Tags: optimization, floating-point, computer-arithmetic

What kind of optimisations does the option `-ffast-math` do ?

I saw that the time taken for a simple $O(n^2)$ algorithm being reduced to that of an $O(n)$ algorithm using the option.

Comment: I think this question already has an answer on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420665/what-does-gccs-ffast-math-actually-do

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as a duplicate of a question on a [different SE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7420665/what-does-gccs-ffast-math-actually-do).

Comment: @BillBarth: Closing a question as a duplicate generally only works within a given StackExchange site, with the exception of obvious cross-posts. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172307/duplicate-questions-on-other-se-sites on Meta StackExchange for discussion and possible solutions.

Comment: @GeoffOxberry, I saw that and tried a plan B.

Comment: @BillBarth where do you think I could find an elaborate answer ?

Comment: @Kirill's answer is a good start.

Answer (score 7):

[There is a canonical answer to this question in GCC's wiki](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FloatingPointMath), which is presumably maintained, it is by far the most authoritative source of information for this type of question. This question, on the other hand, may eventually go out of date.
This is all explained in more detail in the wiki, with examples. The following is essentially a quote from it to illustrate how it answers this exact question, with minor comments:

- `-fno-signaling-nans`
- `-fno-trapping-math`

  > IEEE standard recommends that implementations allow trap handlers to handle exceptions like divide by zero and overflow. This flags assumes that no use-visible trap will happen.
- `-funsafe-math-optimizations` - These optimizations break the laws of floating-point arithmetic and may replace them with the laws of ordinary infinite-precision arithmetic:

  > Due to roundoff errors the associative law of algebra do not necessary hold for floating point numbers and thus expressions like (x + y) + z are not necessary equal to x + (y + z).
- `-ffinite-math-only` - Special quantities such as `inf` or `nan` are assumed never to appear, this saves the time spent looking for them and handling them appropriately. For example, should $x - x$ always be equal to $0.0$?
- `-fno-errno-math`

  > disables setting of the errno variable as required by C89/C99 on calling math library routines. For Fortran this is the default.
- `-fcx-limited-range`

  > causes the range reduction step to be omitted when performing complex division. This uses $a / b = ((ar*br + ai*bi)/t) + i((ai*br - ar*bi)/t)$ with $t = br*br + bi*bi$ and might not work well on arbitrary ranges of the inputs.
- `-fno-rounding-math`
- `-fno-signed-zeros`

  > Due to roundoff errors the associative law of algebra do not necessary hold for floating point numbers and thus expressions like (x + y) + z are not necessary equal to x + (y + z).

Strictly speaking the implications of the last two are not always as intuitive as one might think. For example (see wiki), what about $ -(a - a) = a - a$, is it $+0.0$ or $-0.0$? I believe there is a fair amount of literature on the exact implications, especially by [Bill Kahan](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/).

- Not directly mentioned (I don't see it?), but with `-ffast-math`, certain common special functions such as the reciprocal $1/x$ and the square root $\sqrt{x}$ are replaced with less precise versions that are faster, but which still have some "tolerable" error levels (versus 0ulp error required by the standard) - [here, for example, is what precision is usually provided by glibc's libm](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Errors-in-Math-Functions.html#Errors-in-Math-Functions). Indeed, this is the most common cause of speedup from `-ffast-math`, in code that does a lot of arithmetic with divisions and square roots, almost to the point that I (*personally*) think the other suboptions (`-ffinite-math-only` and the like especially - signalling `NaN`s are quite useful for debugging) cause a bit too much hassle in terms of their cost/benefit.

> I saw that the time taken for a simple $O(n^2)$ algorithm being reduced to that of an $O(n)$ algorithm using the option.

I believe this is improbable and it is possible you made a mistake in your analysis. Unsafe floating-point optimizations might make individual expressions somewhat cheaper to evaluate by virtue of having a larger choice of optimizations. But the speedup should always be at most a constant factor. Is it possible you compared an $O(n^2)$ algorithm with an $O(n)$ for insufficiently large $n$?

Answer (score 1):

An $n^2$ algorithm can be reduced to something that behaves $O(n)$ if, for example, if $n$ is known to the compiler, and is a multiple of the vector size for the vector instructions (if any) supported by the processor. If the compiler can see all of this, it can unroll an inner loop and use vector instructions to do the work. This may reduce the overall operations done to a mere handful and improve the performance substantially.

My read is that `fast-math` doesn't enable such optimization, but it could if they are implicitly enabled by the `unsafe-math-optimizations` due to associativity restrictions that are disabled therein.

Comment: This answer is wrong. Vectorization would not turn an O(n^2) algorithm into an O(n) algorithm, it would only reduce the runtime by a constant factor.

Comment: @Stuntddude, if $n$ is small enough, then an inner loop might be removed entirely, reducing the order of an algorithm.

Comment: if n is a small number known at compile time, then it is already a constant factor, and not part of the time complexity of the algorithm.

Comment: Even if $n$ isn't known at compile-time, it may be unrolled and vectorized far enough that the loop is never entered and thus $O(n)$. The only way to tell would be to have a look at $n$ in a fast version of the code and see.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you other than that you fundamentally do not understand what time complexity is.

Comment: The `n` in `O(n)` represents a quantity *that varies*, i.e. not a constant. Even if the compiler for some reason unrolls the first `k` iterations of a loop of unkown (and therefore potentially unbounded) length (which compilers generally do not do, because it would be a fairly stupid attempt at optimization for many reasons) and `n` happens to always be less than `k`, it will still be O(n) because running through `n` iterations of an unrolled loop is still `O(n)`. Unrolling is not magic, you still have to actually do `n` rounds of work for `n` iterations.

Comment: @Stuntddude, of course all the required work must be done eventually, but some of it may be able to be done in parallel if $n$ is small enough. I’ve seen the Intel compiler put many versions of a loop in an optimized executable.